# remove element from xpath tree not working

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have a problem removing elements from my xpath list.
I am a rookie in Python and HTML scraping, so bear with me :)
I've read that `nodes.getparent().remove(nodes)` should remove an element, but I can't even compile it.
So it seems like I am not getting the element type that I need to be able to remove.
I am able to call `nodes.getparent()` without problems, but not remove on that.

> Error: 
>   "TypeError: Argument 'element' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult)"

Best regards
Jesper

```python
from lxml import html
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Fiddler', 'Host': 'bilmodel.dk'}

page = requests.get('https://bilmodel.dk/Sitemap/Biler', headers=headers)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will create a list of car brands
CarBrands = tree.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/ul[1]//text()')
for nodes in CarBrands:
    if nodes.find('\r\n\t\t\t\t') == 0:
        print('Found it')
        nodes.getparent().remove(nodes)

# Press Enter to exit window
#CarBrand = input('Write car brand:')
print(CarBrands)
```

Comment: what is your initial goal? what you want your script to do?

Comment: Your XPath with `//text()` selects text nodes and not element node, the `remove` method is supposed to remove element nodes, not text nodes. Additionally, with lxml and Python the treatment of text nodes is special, they are returned as smart strings, see http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath-return-values. As for your problem, can you post a snippet of the HTML you are parsing and explain which element(s) you want to remove?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The list looks something like this:
['\r\n\t\t', 'AC', '\r\n\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t\t', 'Ace', '\r\n\t\t\t\t', 'Cobra', '\r\n\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t', '\r\n\t\t', 'Alfa Romeo',.... Where e.g. AC is a parent to Ace and Cobra and Alfa Romeo is a new parent, etc. Looking at https://bilmodel.dk/Sitemap/Biler it's more obvious what I mean. So I just want this list in an intutive manner, so it would be easy to search through.
And there is probably a mucher easier way of doing it, than the path I am heading down ;)

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: I am not getting the element type that I need to be able to remove

The Element you want to Remove is a "**special text node**", instead of removing, clear it by assigning a Blank `''`.

For instance:

```
# Get all <li> inside <ul>[1]
 CarBrands = tree.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/ul[1]/li')

# Iterate all <li> Nodes
for node in CarBrands:
    # Findall <ul><li>...</li> ...
    li_nodes = node.findall('./ul/li')

    # Iterate all <li>
    for li in li_nodes:
        # Find the <a> inside <li>
        a = li.find('./a')

        # Clear "special text nodes"
        a.tail = ''
        print('a:{}'.format(etree.tostring(a)))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> a:b'<a href="/Biler/AC/Ace/">Ace</a>'  
> a:b'<a href="/Biler/AC/Cobra/">Cobra</a>'
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: Thank you for your reply, stovfl. When I run your code my list is not like your output, however :S So the things that you remove with "Clear special text nodes" is that the text that is still present in my output?

**Output:**
a:b'<a href="/Biler/AC/Ace/">Ace</a>'
a:b'<a href="/Biler/AC/Cobra/">Cobra</a>'
a:b'<a href="/Biler/Alfa_Romeo/145/">145</a>'

**Tested with Python: 3.6.0**

Comment: @JesperSR: It's the same, Formating Issue **HTML** must be Formated as **Code**. Read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)